# $\lim 2^n r^{n^2}$ if $0<r<1$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to find for some $0<r<1$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2^nr^{n^2}.$$
I plugged in a few numbers and know that it should go to zero but I don't know how to justify it using limits.

Comment: In fact, the series $\sum 2^{n}r^{n^{2}}$ converges by root test.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Have you tried to apply the root test? It seems such sequence converges to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$L := \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n r^{n^2} \implies \ln(L) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln(2) + n^2 \ln(r)$$

Clearly, the latter term will outpace the former in terms of growth, so

$$\ln(L) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln(2) + n^2 \ln(r) = \ln(r) \lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 = -\infty$$

since $r \in (0,1) \implies \ln(r) < 0$. Thus, since $L \ge 0$ clearly, we can conclude,

$$L = \lim_{x \to -\infty} e^x = 0$$

Comment: Nice answer! Shouldn't be $\ln |r|$ inatead of $\ln r$ ? (Since $r^{n^2}$ is positive).

Comment: $\ln(r) = \ln|r|$ since $r$ is positive.

Comment: Now I see in the title of question we have $|r|<1$  but in the body of the question it is $0<r<1$ !